# What happened to code.intuit.com

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am browsing the IPP API explorer for version 2 and there are multiple links for sample files that have URLs starting with code.intuit.com. For example the BlueDotMenuServlet.java example on this page https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0060_auth_auth/widgets/blue_dot_menu/menu_proxy_code seems to just bring me to the homepage. Is there a centralized location for finding these kind of examples as well as the jars for com.intuit.utils?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code.intuit.com is no longer available. There is a new code repository in GitHub.
Link - https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/

Comment: Does Intuit have any plans to put a proper redirect in place, rather than have code.intuit.com pointing to about.intuit.com, which doesn't really make any sense? You guys broke and awful lot of links and it's confusing an awful lot of people...

Comment: @KeithPalmer - I agree that thr r couple of such links. It will be fixed ASAP.

Comment: While you're at it, you may want to remove the broken version of the OSR that's here: http://dev.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/OSR/OnscreenRef.html

Comment: I developed for the QB web connector through qbXML a while ago and seemed to have a lot of the same issues.. broken links and whatnot.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. We are fixing all these broken links(thr r some references to code.intuit.com). If you face similar issue with any other links in docs, then please mention it here, we will fix this ASAP.

Comment: Is there some where we can report these that's NOT on StackOverflow? StackOverflow is NOT the appropriate place to report broken links, and I have emailed various people at Intuit many, many times trying to get these issues fixed, and they just seem to always get ignored.

Comment: ok. Please raise a support ticket mentioning all these links. I will make sure, all of those will be fixed ASAP.

Comment: Support Page -https://developer.intuit.com/docs/9_other_resources/0030_support/0010_submit_support_incidents

Comment: OK, I submitted a support ticket for that.